# Trying to read a file and display the values in c

Tags: c

So i need to read a file that lists all the z table values, the file looks like this:
0.5 0.50399 0.50798 0.51197 0.51595 0.51994 0.52392 0.5279  0.53188 0.53586
0.5398  0.5438  0.54776 0.55172 0.55567 0.55966 0.5636  0.56749 0.57142 0.57535
0.5793  0.58317 0.58706 0.59095 0.59483 0.59871 0.60257 0.60642 0.61026 0.61409
0.61791 0.62172 0.62552 0.6293  0.63307 0.63683 0.64058 0.64431 0.64803 0.65173
0.65542 0.6591  0.66276 0.6664  0.67003 0.67364 0.67724 0.68082 0.68439 0.68793 and it continues on listing the numbers in the distribution table but it wont allow me to put the whole file here. The code results in the correct amount of values but all the values are 0.0000.

heres the code:

```
int main ()
{
float value;
float  arrayname[31][10];
int i,j;
printf("This script calculated the Z-value for a given value. From the list below, please select a value:\n");
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("distribution.txt", "r");
if (fp==NULL)exit(1);

for(i=0;i<31;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%f ", &arrayname[i][j]);
    }
}

for(i=0;i<31;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        printf("%f ", arrayname[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%f ", &arrayname[i][j]);` --> `fscanf(fp, "%d ", &arrayname[i][j]);`

Comment: That did not make a difference, just to be clear the text file that i am trying to display has decimal values such as 0.5 0.50399 0.50798 0.51197 0.51595 0.51994 0.52392 0.5279 0.53188 0.53586

Comment: Are you *sure* that the exact code you have posted causes the *exact* results you describe?

Comment: @Lilac Yes, it makes a difference, using a wrong format specifier is undefined behaviour, switch to `float  arrayname[31][10];` if you want floats

Comment: If that's what's in your text file, then you _should_ be using `%f` in scanf and printf, but `arrayname` should be declared as `double arrayname[31][10]` (*not* `float`).  But under no circumstances should the code shown be printing `qo▓qo▓...` -- nonsense numbers, yes, garbage characters, no.  So, like EOF, I am wondering whether you might have run a slightly different program than the one you showed us.  Please double-check that.

Comment: This is exactly what the result is, it changes sometimes but its usually the same"This script calculated the Z-value for a given value. From the list below, please select a value:
qoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿ
qoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿ
qoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿ
qoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿ
qoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿ
qoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿ
qoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿqoÿ..."

Comment: Oh ghod, I see it now.

Comment: after i changed it to double arrayname[31][10] it changed to "This script calculated the Z-value for a given value. From the list below, please select a value:
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo

qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo

qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo

qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo

qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo

qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo
qo"

Comment: You can not use `%f` with `double`s in `scanf`, use `%lf`

Comment: using %lf with double did not make a difference in the result either

Comment: Man, you need to distinguish between code that works and correct code!

Comment: @DavidRanieri Doh! I could have _sworn_ `%f` scanned into a `double` and you had to write `%hf` if you wanted to scan into a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

This is where the garbage is coming from:

```
    printf(fp, "%f ", arrayname[i][j]);
           ^^^
```

You've got `printf` mixed up with `fprintf`.  `printf` does not take an initial `FILE *` argument.  The C library is trying to interpret the data in the `FILE` object as a format string, and never even trying to print your numbers.  Change this line to

```
    printf("%f ", arrayname[i][j]);
```

You also need to fix the declaration of `arrayname`.  You have decimal floating-point numbers in your file, so `%f` is the right format specifier, but `scanf("%f ", &x)` expects `x` to be a `float`, not an `int`.  Change the declaration to

```
float arrayname[31][10];
```

Your compiler should have caught both of these bugs.  Turn on all the warnings, and until you have a lot more experience, treat *all* warnings as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: This made the warnings go away, but now it does not display anything after "This script calculated the Z-value for a given value. From the list below, please select a value:"

Comment: @Lilac Could you try again with `float arrayname[31][10]` please?  I was wrong about how `%f` works in `scanf`.

Comment: now it shows values but they are all 0.0000

Comment: I don't know why that would be happening.  My first guess would be that `scanf` is interpreting the file incorrectly, and in order to dig into that I would need to see _precisely_ what is in the file, perhaps even with a hex dump.  I think you should ask a new question in which you include the complete text of the file you're trying to read as well as the code with the corrections we've already made here.

Comment: will do, thank you for the help